# Scope UIView animations to specific views or properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have a UIView with subviews and want to animate only specific properties of certain views. For example, I sometimes want to call `[self layoutIfNeeded]` and animate only the bounds but not other properties of the view or its subviews.

The problem is that `+[UIView animateWithDuration:animations]` tracks subviews and all animatable properties. Is there a reasonable solution to this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at `+[UIView performWithoutAnimation:]`. You specify a block of changes you wish to perform without animation and they happen immediately.

This is good for iOS7 and above, and only for UIKit animation. For dealing with animations on layer objects directly, or support for older versions of iOS, you can use the following code:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
//Perform any changes that you do not want to be animated
[CATransaction commit];
```

More on `performWithoutAnimation:` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/performWithoutAnimation%3a) and on `setDisabledActions:` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CATransaction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CATransaction/setDisableActions%3a).

---

If you do not wish to alter the parent's code, you can implement the setter methods of the properties you do not wish animated, and wrap the super call with `performWithoutAnimation:`, like so:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    [UIView performWithoutAnimation: ^ { 
        [super setFrame:frame]; 
    }];
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to enable/disable specific properties from being animated? For example, `[self layoutIfNeeded]` changes the frame of the view but also changes the frames of its subviews. I want to tell UIKit to animate just the parent view but not the subviews without modifying the implementation of the parent view.

Comment: @ide You can modify the subview implementation of `setXXX:` to wrap it in a `performWithoutAnimation:` block. See edit to answer.

Comment: Yey the CATransaction thing worked and performWithoutAnimation was somehow glitching in a tableview :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the subviews to resize when the parent view bounds change, you should set each of the subviews' `autoresizingMask` appropriately and/or set the parent's `autoresizesSubviews` flag.

Otherwise you have to override the parent's `layoutSubviews` and modify each of the subviews' frames back to their previous values.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to do something a bit more complex than just moving a view I would absolutely suggest you step down from UIKit to Core Animation. This will allow you to create animations on specific key paths for each object.

I promise it's not that scary, by creating a few CABasicAnimations and grouping them together in a CAAnimationGroup you can add them to any UIView's CALayer. This will definitely provide the control you need.